# Error importing pygame

Tags: windows, pygame, python-3.3

I'm using python 3.3, on a windows 8 system, and have tried downloading all of the available python3.3 versions of pygame from bitbucket.

During the "Select Python Installation" page, it doesn't seem to be able to find my python installation, defaulting to "Python from another location".  When this is chosen, "import pygame" returns the common error of "module not found".

When I choose "feature will be installed on local hard drive", I can then type in the file path of my python, and then it seems to actually succeed, and it gets installed in what I think (but obviously don't know) is the correct location.  But, when I try to import it after after this, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I cannot find any fixes for this error online, so any help that I can get from people on here how to fix it would be hugely appreciated.  I apologize if anything is unclear and for my lack of experience.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has probably happened is you installed a 64-bit version of `pygame` when your base Python installation is 32-bit. Assuming that your machine is 64-bit-capable, and you're running a 64-bit version of Windows, download the [64-bit Python installer](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/python-3.3.3.amd64.msi) of Python 3.3 from python.org and install it. It will overwrite the 32-bit version of Python 3.3 you already have. Then, get the Python 3.3 amd64 version of Pygame (pygame-1.9.2a0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe) from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame), Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows respository. While unofficial and not supported, I've never had an issue with any of the packages here, as long as any prerequisites are also installed. I'd also recommend downloading the amd64-py3.3 version of [NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) from the same place, as it can speed up pygame in some instances.

In the future, make sure you know exactly what version and bitness of Python you're running before blindly downloading and trying to run module installers from the internet. Secondly, if you need a third-party module, check Gohlke's repository first.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! Will try that out right now.

Comment: @user3113022 - If my answer was helpful, feel free to click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted. We both earn reputation points, and it marks the question as resolved. Thanks! See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading and installing the 2.7 version alongwith it downloadand install the pygame 2.7.msi it works on installing

Comment: That shoud rather be a comment